# South-up projection/setting in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Is there a south-up setting for a projection in QGIS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rotate your map (without projection requirements) :

- In the canvas, use the field "Rotation" at the bottom of the main window :
  [image]
- In composer, use the "Map rotation" field of the main properties of your map :

[image]

Comment: Will labels be upside down if I do this?

Comment: For any vector layers, labels will be good. For image raster (OpenStreetMap), I think labels will be revesed. I can't test today but you can test easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the **project** CRS to a south-up projection like `EPSG:22281 Cape / Lo21`, you will get a map with the South pole upwards:

[image]

Note that common raster basemaps like Openstreetmap will have labels upside down as well with this projection, whereas labels of your vector data will appear in a readable orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a south-up CRS with `+axis=wsu`.
That indicates `X` is west, `Y` is south, `Z` is up.

It doesn't save that in the `prj` file though. When you load a layer with this projection, you have to set the CRS in the layer properties. Other than that it works properly.

Comment: QGIS saves `AXIS["Y",WEST],AXIS["X",SOUTH]` in the **.qpj** file.  So good as long as you work with QGIS, bad if you work on in GDAL or Arcgis (they don't read the .qpj file). The `Cape Lo` projection has `PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator_South_Orientated"]` in the .prj file, which seems to work correctly.